# Why do Tarjan's and Kosaraju's algorithms for finding strongly connected components have the same running-time complexity?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I followed an explanation of [Kosaraju's](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/) and [Tarjan's](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tarjan-algorithm-find-strongly-connected-components/) strongly-connected components algorithms, and they say that both have O(|V|+|E|) time complexity.

That didn't make sense to me since Kosaraju uses two DFS passes and computes the transposed graph, but Tarjan's use only one DFS.

Comment: You seem to think that Landau notation is way more useful/informative [than it really is](http://reitzig.github.io/ramblings/2016/how-useful-is-landau-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > they say that both have O(|V|+|E|) time complexity.
>
> that didn't make sens for me since Kosaraju use two dfs pass and compute transpose graph, but Tarjan's use only one dfs

If you check the definition of Landau notation you will see that it does not say which function is smaller, that is (here) which algorithm is *faster*. It ignores constant factors.

Both algorithms have running times in $\Theta(|V| + |E|)$; that does not preclude one of them being $2^{100}$ times faster than the other for all $n \leq 2^{100}$.

Comment: "for all n < 2^100" -> What's n here, just curious? Is it |V| or |E|?

Comment: @theprogrammer Good point. I probably intended it to be vertex count, but input size would also work for the argument.